# Preact: Generate "No build tools route" like code from buildtools

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, rollupjs, preact

Currently I'm experimenting with Preact, Rollup and Typescript.
The idea is to create a sort of components library where all the dependencies are coming from CDN.

The idea is to have e.g. this product.tsx file:

```js
import { FunctionalComponent } from 'preact';
import register from 'preact-custom-element';

interface ProductProps {
  name: string;
}

const Product: FunctionalComponent<ProductProps> = ({name}: ProductProps) => <p>Hello {name}</p>;

register(Product, 'x-product', ['name'], { shadow: false });
```

And from this the TypeScript + Bundler generating something like this (product.js, of course can be further minified):

```js
(function) {
'use strict';

    const Product = ({ name }) => preact_10_19_3.h("p", null,
        "Hello ",
        name);
    preact-custom-element_4_3_0.register(Product, 'x-product', ['name'], { shadow: false });

})();
```

So this file can be used in an index.html where we can load the dependencies from the CDN and alias them (to avoid possible version conflict)

```html
<body>
  <!-- Load from CDN -->
  <script src="cdn/10.19.3/preact.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Alias  -->
  <script>
    window.preact_10_19_3 = preact;
  </script>
  <!-- Register x-product webcomponent -->
  <script src="./product.js"></script>

  <!-- Use webcomponent -->
  <x-product name="Test" />

</body>
```

Do you have any idea/suggestion how to do this?
I've found some promising configuration (rollup 'iife' format) but most of these libraries are not very well documented.
Maybe I should try webpack instead?
Does this "load time gain" with CDN worth at all?

Comment: There is no "load time gain" from CDN -- they are quite sub-optimal, but let you skip build tools which can make them easier to start with. Using UMD global is quite out-dated, why not use ESM with import maps? You can ship your library as standard Node ESM and use [import maps](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started#using-preact-with-htm-and-importmaps) to let it work in the browser.

Comment: I think the only drawback to use importmap is that you are cannot use it with integrity, so you cannot verify the lib checksum, which can be a security issue.

Comment: It's only a downside if you're pulling from CDNs, which again, is rather suboptimal. Serving it yourself mostly gets around this. Might be able to use [this](https://github.com/guybedford/import-maps-extensions#integrity) though, but it does come with some overhead.